# which is better for my project: Django, Plone, php, or ruby on rails

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, django, plone

I have a php video hosting site, not a typical video hosting site, but i think you put it in that category.

I'm almost done with it, I'll launch it maybe next week, i created it in php because my partner wanted to get it done so fast, and the fastest way for me to do it was php, because i know it could be done with php mysql, ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php and some other multimedia packages. I don't know what it takes to do it in other languages.

now I want to launch the site, and re-write another better version, because i don't like the current version, my partner likes it but he's on the business side and I'm on the development side lol, so i decide :D

I don't know much about the php frameworks, I've seen them all, but I don't think they are that good for such websites

I was thinking maybe Django, but Django is created mainly for CMS websites, I don't know if i can use it for my site

I've never used plone but i think it's good for my site, I don't have experience with it so I would like to know what you think

Ruby on rails seems to be another option but I've never seen any video hosting site using ROR

So what is the best language to re-write my site? or should i stick with php?

edit

i already know python, so it's not hard for me to switch to python framwork if it's better for such project...I have some ROR knowledge...and I'm gonna use php for now as you said guys but I'm talking about the future

I don't want to make this question an argumentative question, because it will be closed, so let ask another question, can i do such website with django because i know django, but i have never used it for such thing, i used it for cms, i don't know if it supports ffmpeg, multimedia and such things

sorry for posting an argumentative topic, i hope my question is now better :D

Comment: This is not going to lead to a constructive discussion, You can use any of the frameworks to accomplish what you want to do. And while I might recommend one language or framework someone else might suggest another valid option. Use the language that you know well and generally you can do anything with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we use PHP or Pylons for our WebApp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409812/should-we-use-pylons-or-php-for-our-webapp/2409852#2409852)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should stick with PHP :

- you already know the language
- you already have the tools for development
- you already have a code base

I think you should see how your site behaves in production and see what are the most wanted user needs before spending time rewriting everything, and during this time not beeing able to answer correctly to their needs.

And while your site sends its first bits, it will give you a lot more info on what to expect from the version 2, from a technical point of view.

Edit : I am not pro-php, I just think you should stick whit the language you already know, until your business gives you time to learn something else.

Answer (score 3):

It does not really matter in which language you would make it. If you are good programmer, the application will work fine in any of those environment. If you are not good programmer, it will sux always :) you can do it for example in Ruby on Rails, but what is the purpose if you will not be able to follow MVC structure? it's a little bit risky to use technology that you do not know. There are many issues you can run into. Just for example N+1 queries. I wouldn't recommend you switching the language, unless you really would like to learn other technology - but be aware that your application most probably will not be "pretty" :)